# JW Player/ColorBox callbacks not firing

Tags: jquery, colorbox, jwplayer

Using JW Player with ColorBox and jQuery and it does not appear that the callbacks are firing correctly. Here's a snippet:

```
    $(".thumbnail").live('click', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var videoFile = $(this).attr('id');

        jwplayer('viewPort').setup({
                    'flashplayer': '../jwplayer/player.swf',
                           'file': 'data/' + videoFile,
                             'id': 'playerID',
                          'width': '100%',
                         'height': '100%',
                     'controlbar':'bottom',
            'controlbar.idlehide':'false',
                           'skin':'../jwplayer/skins/big.zip',
                        'plugins': {
                                    'gapro-2': { },
                                   },
                     'onComplete': function () {
                                      $("#colorBox").colorbox.close();
                                   }
        });

        $("#colorBox").colorbox({
               'width':"80%",
              'height':"80%",
          'transition':"fade",
           'scrolling':false,
              'inline':true,
                'href':"#viewPort",
                'open':true,
          'onComplete': function () {
                            jwplayer('viewPort').play();
                        },
            'onClosed': function () {
                            jwplayer('viewPort').remove();
                        }
        });

    });
```

The ones not firing are the `onComplete` for `jwplayer` and `colorbox`.

I can execute the command `$("#colorBox").colorbox.close();` in the console (Firebug) and it *does* close. Same for `jwplayer('viewPort').play();`

Could it be a collision between the method names? Because `onClosed` fires just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JWPlayer you are supposed to put the event handlers inside the `events` property of the options object:

```
jwplayer(...).setup({
    ...
    events : {
        onComplete : function () {
            console.log('Chicken\'s Done!');
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a link to the section in the documentation that describes how to register event handlers: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference#Events

I'm not too familiar with Colorbox so I'm not sure how you initialize a callback for it but the documentation states that you can bind to a global `onComplete` event like this:

```
$(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
    setTimeout($.colorbox.next, 1500);
});
```

*Source: http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ (near the bottom are "Event Hooks")*

Comment: I had missed the `events` object! Don't know how many times I read that and still didn't see it. Thanks! As for `cbox_complete`, it's not going to work for me because my trigger elements are being generated dynamically, and I clean up the jwplayer and colorbox each time. But wrapping my jwplayer events in the `events` object got me everything I needed to do! Thanks!!